# How to open multiple files in a directory

Tags: file, python-3.x

I need to build a simple script in python3 that opens more files inside a directory and see if inside these files is a keyword.

All the files inside the directory are like this: "f*.formatoffile" (* stays for a casual number)

Example:

```
f9993546.txt
f10916138.txt
f6325802.txt
```

Obviusly i just need to open the txt files ones.

Thanks in advance!

Final script:

```
import os

Path = "path of files"
filelist = os.listdir(Path)
for x in filelist:
    if x.endswith(".txt"):
        try:
            with open(Path + x, "r", encoding="ascii") as y:
                for line in y:
                    if "firefox" in line:
                        print ("Found in %s !" % (x))
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: You probably want to open one file after the other to check for it.
Google "loop directory python", which will show you how, then post the code you have if you get stuck

Comment: If it always is the same directory, you could try to look into [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

Comment: solved. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import os
Path = "path of the txt files"
filelist = os.listdir(Path)
for i in filelist:
    if i.endswith(".txt"):  # You could also add "and i.startswith('f')
        with open(Path + i, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                # Here you can check (with regex, if, or whatever if the keyword is in the document.)
```

Comment: I tried it and there's a problem. the script is ok, but i just realized that the txt files are all of a different encoding, in fact it says me: [code]UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 5637: invalid continuation byte[/code] is there a way to force all combinations of encoding until the script find the right one?

Comment: I SOLVED! I just use "ascii" that seems the most frequent as encoding, and then I added a try-except, and in 2 seconds it found me the file I was looking for! Thanks again. I'll post the final script on the main